# Can I decide the return type of a method by passing it as a parameter to the method in java?

Tags: java, generics

I am working on an application and while writing a rest client using Jersy I want a single method to return objects of different classes from the method. I can get this done having Object as the return type of the method but I am looking if I can use generics for this, so I don't have to worry for the type safety.

So far I have the following code, but I am not able to get any further with this:

```
public <T> T getContent(final String resourceUrl, Class <T> cls) {
        //"http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/get"
        final Client client = new Client(); final WebResource webResource = client.resource(resourceUrl);
        final ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
        }

        final T output = response.getEntity(cls.getClass());

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");

        //get content
        //return T
        return output;

}
```

Comment: You are already returning `T`. What's the question?

Comment: `response.getEntity(cls.getClass())` should be `response.getEntity(cls)`

Comment: Whats the problem? The code looks to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is right, from a generics point of view you can simply do something like

```
<T> T methodName(Class<T> var);
```

and then pass the expected type while you call it.

```
methodName(Foo.class); // will return an object of the type foo;
```

obviously, you need to make sure that you are handling the typecast inside your method, but it looks like you already done this

for more info check this link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html